# update serialized field value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have serialized the form field values like this

`asset_id=171&inspection_id=99&formid=14&inspection%5BiCompanyFormId%5D=&inspection%5BiEquipmentTypeId%5D=25&inspection%5BiCompanyEquipmentId%5D=171&inspection%5BeAssignedToType%5D=Individual&inspection%5BiAssignedUserId%5D=12&inspection%5BeStatus%5D=Completed&inspection%5Blayout%5D=Table` ..

in this i need to add value for this `inspection%5BiCompanyFormId%5D`...

this is my code

```
var dataq = $('<form id="stat_frm">').append(myInputs).serialize();
```

Comment: What value do you want to add? What is the final expected output?

Comment: sset_id=171&inspection_id=99&formid=14&inspection%5BiCompanyFormId%5D=15&inspection%5BiEquipmentTypeId%5D=25&inspection%5BiCompanyEquipmentId%5D=171&inspection%5BeAssignedToType%5D=Individual&inspection%5BiAssignedUserId%5D=12&inspection%5BeStatus%5D=Completed&inspection%5Blayout%5D=Table

Comment: You need to specify this details in your original question itself. Also in the string that you have shared - what exactly has changed?

Comment: inspection%5BiCompanyFormId%5D=15

Comment: Check the answer I have shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex `replace`

```
var input = "asset_id=171&inspection_id=99&formid=14&inspection%5BiCompanyFormId%5D=&inspection%5BiEquipmentTypeId%5D=25&inspection%5BiCompanyEquipmentId%5D=171&inspection%5BeAssignedToType%5D=Individual&inspection%5BiAssignedUserId%5D=12&inspection%5BeStatus%5D=Completed&inspection%5Blayout%5D=Table";

var output = input.replace(/inspection%5BiCompanyFormId%5D=[^&]*/, "inspection%5BiCompanyFormId%5D=15");
```